# Umbraco: Is there a way to get the list of folder under the Media (Physical Folder)

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, umbraco

I am just trying to create a list (textual value only) of folders under the Media folder (Physical Folder).

Media folder is located at the root folder.(See the image)

[image: Umbraco root folder]

I tried the following code just to test if I can get the last folder:

```
var contentService = Services.ContentService;
var folderList = contentService.GetRootContent().Last();
IContent s = folderList;

string nameOfLastFolder = folderList.Name.ToString();
```

But it returned Home

I also tried the following code:

```
var mediaService = Services.MediaService;
var folderList = mediaService.GetRootMedia().Last();
IMedia s = folderList;

string nameOfLastFolder = folderList.Name.ToString();
```

But it returned the name of the last media file which is correct if what I am trying to get is the media in the backstage but not the physical one. (See the following image)

[image: Media folder]

What I want to get is the list of media folder physically, not in the the backstage view media. I want to create a list of the physical media folder:

[image: Physical Media Folder]

I Hope that you can help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: Why aren't you just looking in the filesystem?
 

string pathToFiles = HttpServerUtility.MapPath("/Media");

string[] fileList = Directory.GetFiles(pathToFiles);

Comment: As Eyescream said you should use the filesystem. The Umbraco Content and Media services look up for nodes in the database, not for actual files.

Comment: Yes, correct, I know that those Content and Media doesn't have anything to do with the actual file itself in the physical file. I will try that code. Thank you very much for responding. :-)

Comment: I guess HttpServerUtility doesn't have a method named as MapPath() as I tried to write it. I searched in the web and as what I saw, there is really a MapPath() method, but it seems that it doesn't work for me. When I write the HttpServerUtility, there are only 4 available methods and there are nothing else more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should loop through the folders in the filesystem instead of using the Umbraco service (which lists the database entries).

Example

```
string pathToFiles = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/Media");
string[] fileList = Directory.GetFiles(pathToFiles);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works fine now.

`string pathToFiles = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/Media");
string[] fileList = Directory.GetDirectories(pathToFiles);`